# doGet XML in Servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I have a method in my java class that downloads an XML file and returns a [org.w3c.dom.Document](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) object.

I will like to get this XML from this java servlet class but can't figure out how to.

I tried this :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        Document document = Allmethods.getXML();

        response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.getWriter().write(document);

    }
```

But it doesn't work because printwriter is not applicable for the document object. How can i archive this ?

Comment: You must serialize the document to a string before you can output it.  It's been awhile since I worked with this but I believe you will need to run the `Document` through an XSL transform with the default stylesheet (identity transform).

Comment: so you want to get DOM object from an XML file is it ?

Answer (score 0):

I  succeeded following the tip from @Jim Garrison.

```
Document document = Allmethods.getXML();

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));
        String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();

        response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.getWriter().write(output);
```